# Change from firestore to mongodb, connect to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm moving my db from firestore to mongodb. I used to call the db with a const.

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
    firebase.firestore().settings({
        cacheSizeBytes: firebase.firestore.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED
    });
```

```
db.collection("users").doc(user.uid)
            .get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                //do something
            } else {
                console.log("No such document!")
            }}).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting document:", error)
            });
```

Now in mongodb, I create if data needed a mongoClient.connect().
Is there a way to call a function or a const and do the same thing like in firestore, or a cleaner way?

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbname = "dbname";
```

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              const db = client.db(dbname);
              let collection = db.collection('users');

              collection.findOne({ _id: user.uid }).then(user => {
                //do something
              }).catch((err) => { console.log(err);
              }).finally(() => { client.close(); });
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. Create a wrapper function for database calls

```
function findOne(query,collectionName,callback){
   MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              const db = client.db(dbname);
              let collection = db.collection(collectionName);

              collection.findOne(query).then(user => {
                callback(null,user);
              }).catch((err) => { callback(err,null);
              }).finally(() => { client.close(); });
          });
}
```

Similarly you can create multiple functions for another operations or you may create only one function and then use it as wrapper. The main idea here is that we can utilise callback mechanism

For consuming it

```
route.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
   findOne({ _id: user.uid },'users',(err,user)=>{res.send(user)})
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats a way to keep it cleaner :)

Comment: If im using a function, I dont get the user infomationen back.

Comment: When I use "user.username", I get the error `ReferenceError: user is not defined`.

Comment: You might be getting any exception before calling the callback.

Comment: What do you mean with exception? Sry for dumb questions :/

Comment: Check console.log(err)